# Reading a file with "latin small letter thorn" as delimiter in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a file that has the "latin small letter thorn" http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe/index.htm as a delimiter. I am trying to use the csv file https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/csv.html API for the same.

I tried various ways to represent the delimiter in the source code, but it always errors out:

```
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.readline(), delimiters='\xc3\xbe')
print dialect.delimiter
```

Error:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/csv.py", line 180, in sniff
    raise Error, "Could not determine delimiter"
_csv.Error: Could not determine delimiter

How do I represent such characters as delimiters in the csv API in python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Python 3 if you can -- it has much better unicode support. Then you can just copy the "small thorn" into your source code and all will be well. In Python 2.6, you need to make sure you set `~*~coding: utf-8~*~` at the top of the file and use `u''` unicode strings and such. Also, mind your Python versions. You are linking to the Python 3 docs but your error is Python 2.6!

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use python 3 :(. I tried setting the encoding via # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- and entering the delimiters as delimiters=u'\u00FE', but that doesnt solve the problem either :(

Comment: It seems highly unlikely to use a Unicode multibyte alphabetic as a CSV delimiter. Are you sure the file is UTF-8?

Comment: Your question reminded me of this graphic:
http://media-cache-cd0.pinimg.com/736x/9b/e3/94/9be394578a2ceb735c80eb7d18eb94d8.jpg  
If it's a one-time task, anything is legit - you might as well open it in a word processor and change all the `þ` to "normal" CRs.
Otherwise, have you tried `ord('þ')` and then possibly `chr(ord('þ'))` to check which char to look for your system?

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('yourfile.csv', 'r').read().split('\n')
for i in f:
    i = i.split('þ')
    print i
```

Comment: This is somewhat confusing, because you're not using a Unicode literal (e.g. u'þ'), so you end up with a string that's using your interpreter's default coding.

Comment: When I do this with a CSV containing "testingþtwoþthree \n
fourþfiveþsix" it works.

Comment: Yes, if either both or none of them are Unicode. In your case, you're reading the file contents as `bytes` (`str`), so it works fine.